# Is there a name for DTOs intended to pass data between classes or methods?

Tags: design-patterns, dto

As I understand a DTO should be used to pass information between two different processes or machines.
I'd like to know if objects similar to DTOs in the sense of containing no business logic, but intended to pass information between methods or classes have a special name (maybe model objects?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within a domain model, [Value Object](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html) might be more what you're looking for?

DTO is an often overloaded term that means different things to different people. However, if you look at Fowler's [definition](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html), there's definitely a bias toward their use in promoting efficiency in a remote communication context rather than a domain model context.